# Matching end of line in Google Test's ASSERT_DEATH regex

Tags: c++, regex, googletest

Using Google Test for a unit test of an assert wrapper that can optionally include `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` info in the error message.

```
void My_Assert (bool test)
{
#if USE_FILE_MACRO
    std::cerr << "fatal error: false in file __FILE__ at line __LINE__\n"
#else
    std::cerr << "fatal error: false\n"
#endif
    throw std::runtime_error ("Fatal error"); 
}
```

I want to ensure for this test that the file and line are *not* included, so I only want `ASSERT_DEATH` to match on "fatal error: false", not "fatal error: false in file my_file.cpp at line 42".
This is what I'm starting with:

```
ASSERT_DEATH( try {My_Assert (false);} catch (...){exit(1);}, "fatal error: false" );
```

I tried adding a dollar sign to match the end of line, but that doesn't match on "fatal error:false". I tried different variants of `\s`, `[:space:]` with no luck. I may be misunderstanding the doc, and a dollar sign doesn't match end of line in gtest's regex: I can't tell if the statement "matches the end of a string (not that of each line)" in the [advanced guide here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md) applies only to Windows regex or all systems. I'm compiling for OSX using LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31).

Comment: Not enough information given unfortunately. 1. Provide a [MCVE] 2. Give some details about your target platform and compiler version used. Improve your question please! BTW, does the process _crash_ with a non-zero exit value in 1st place?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ
Updated the question with more info.
The function under test (My_Assert) does not crash - just logs to stderr and throws an exception.

Comment: `ASSERT_DEATH()`expects your program to exit with a non zero exit code in 1st place, before the regex is checked actually. You're probably using it wrong.

Comment: Where's the regex?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - +1 to "probably using it wrong", but I don't really know how to use it right. I've got that exit(1) in the catch of the ASSERT_DEATH expression, so it's definitely crashing (the sub-process) when running the test.

Comment: @Laurel: The regex is `fatal error: false`, which obviously doesn't work because it will match for "fatal error: falseFOLLOWED_BY_ANYTHING_AT_ALL_OR_NOTHING". I tried `"fatal error: false$"`, which didn't match "fatal error: false" (let alone fail to match "fatal error: false plus other stuff").

Comment: @kslattery Why not just take the last 18 characters from the string and see if they are equal to `fatal error: false`?

Comment: I suspect you need to match `false` at the end of both line and string. Use `($|\n)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That did the trick. It turns out that just "...false\n" does it. I thought I'd tried that, but I probably did something stupid like adding an extra backslash to be sure "\n" would be passed to the regex engine.
I think you need to submit this as an answer for me to accept it as one, though?
Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to account for a newline symbol after `false`, use `false\n`.

If you need to match `false` at the end of both line and string use `($|\n)`.